# Preprocess title field in all contexts (sitewide)

Tags: entities, theming

If you put a backslash in a title of a node I need to rewrite that title and remove the backslash wrapping the text after in  tags. I'm currently doing this using multiple preprocess functions. It seems that I have to create a new preprocess function for every context that a title might appear in:

```
function project_preprocess_page(&vars){/*rewrite*/}
function project_preprocess_node(&vars){/*rewrite*/}
function project_preprocess_node(&vars){/*rewrite*/}
function project_preprocess_panels_pane(&$vars){/*rewrite*/}
```

This is working but it's frustrating (and probably inefficient) as there are so many different contexts where titles are displayed.

It seems like there should be a function where I can just override this once and not worry about it anymore. Can anyone suggest a solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure [hook_node_view](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_view/7) can do it for you, but you might need to call [drupal_set_title](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_set_title/7) on some situations.